# State change not picked up by subscription in component

Tags: angular, state, ngrx

I'm using ngrx to provide state management in an Angular2 app. I have two components: `MenuComponent` and `ResultsPanelComponent` that subscribe to different values provided by the same slice of state.

The problem I'm seeing is that the "menu" component responds to the state change but the "results" component does not when I log the value of the state.

I'm dispatching the action to populate the state in a higher order component.

**menu.component.ts**

```js
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private sub: Subscription;
  newReportHeaderCount: number;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.store.select('results').subscribe((state) => {
      console.log('MenuComponent state: ', state);
      this.newReportHeaderCount = state['newReportHeaderCount'];
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**results.component.ts**

```js
export class ResultsPanelComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private sub: Subscription;
  reportHeaderSummary: ReportHeaderSummary[] = [];

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.store.select('results').subscribe((state) => {
      console.log('ResultsPanelComponent state: ', state);
      this.reportHeaderSummary = state['reportHeaderSummary'];
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

When I run my app, I see:

```
MenuComponent state:  Object {reportHeaderSummary: Array[0], reportHeaders: Array[0], newReportHeaderCount: 0, loading: false}
ResultsPanelComponent state:  Object {reportHeaderSummary: Array[0], reportHeaders: Array[0], newReportHeaderCount: 0, loading: false}
MenuComponent state:  Object {reportHeaderSummary: Array[4], reportHeaders: Array[0], newReportHeaderCount: 3, loading: false}
```

logged to the console. I would expect to see one more log statement for `ResultsPanelComponent state` when the state was changed.

The `ResultsPanelComponent` is in a different module than `MenuComponent`, but both are contained within the same parent module that dispatches the action to load data.

**[Update]**

I made an additional action to increment the `newReportHeaderCount` value, and when dispatched from either `MenuComponent` or `ResultsPanelComponent`, the state is correct, but the new values are not pushed to all components that subscribe to the `results` slice of state.

I only see the new state value in the component that dispatched the action.

If I move the dispatch of the action to the higher order component, I only see the state change in `MenuComponent`

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was loading my EffectListener and provideStore in a module that was shared across several other modules.

I moved those to my root `AppModule` and everything works as expected.